# How can I pass a list of pairs to an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to write an Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure that takes as a parameter a list of pairs of some other type, say `varchar2(32)`.  Is this possible?  What's the best way to do it?

Comment: How do you want to call this stored proc? From Java, from .net, from sql or pl/sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to pass in a collection, i.e.

```
SQL> create type point as object (
  2    x_coordinate number,
  3    y_coordinate number );
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> create type point_array
  2  is
  3  table of point;
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> create procedure interpolate( points IN point_array )
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    points point_array := point_array( point(0,1), point(1,1) );
  3  begin
  4    interpolate( points );
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Obviously, in reality, the function would do something with the array that was passed in, but that's the general idea.

Comment: If all I want to use the `point_array` in a procedure defined in a package, can I also define `point` and `point_array` in that same package?

Comment: Yes, you can declare the collection in the package.  In that case, though, you'd want POINT to be a record rather than an object.  But the rest of the code would be identical.

Comment: Thanks.  I also changed the `as` to `is` to get it to compile.